# Svelte subscribe to multiple store value

Tags: store, svelte

Coming from Vue I am still in delight and confusion of Sveltes store.

How would I write this ... :

```
import { count, timer } from '$stores/countAndTimer';


let count_value;

const unsubscribe = count.subscribe(value => {
    count_value = value;
});

onDestroy(unsubscribe);
```

... if I would have multiple values from store?

I tried:

```
let count_value;
let timer_value;

const unsubscribeCount = count.subscribe(value => {
    count_value = value;
});


const unsubscribeTimer = timer.subscribe(value => {
    count_timer = value;
});

onDestroy(unsubscribeCount);
onDestroy(unsubscribeTimer);
```

But it seems to be tied to that variable name subscribe.

What is best approach for that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can I do instead: $: $count; and $: $timer; and be fine?

Comment: Just use $count and $value, and svelte will do all the cleaning on destroy, no need to go with subscribe methods unless you have to handle the number of subscribers and that sort of things